# Doing a/(a+b) in Sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I am doing the following code but I cannot get the correct percentage as output

```
Select
name,
fans,
useful,
funny,
(useful/(Select (useful+funny) from user)) As useful_percent
From user
Order by fans desc
limit 10
```

The output is like this,

```
+-----------+------+--------+--------+----------------+
| name      | fans | useful |  funny | useful_percent |
+-----------+------+--------+--------+----------------+
| Amy       |  503 |   3226 |   2554 |             36 |
| Mimi      |  497 |    257 |    138 |              2 |
| Harald    |  311 | 122921 | 122419 |           1381 |
| Gerald    |  253 |  17524 |   2324 |            196 |
| Christine |  173 |   4834 |   6646 |             54 |
| Lisa      |  159 |     48 |     13 |              0 |
| Cat       |  133 |   1062 |    672 |             11 |
| William   |  126 |   9363 |   9361 |            105 |
| Fran      |  124 |   9851 |   7606 |            110 |
| Lissa     |  120 |    455 |    150 |              5 |
+-----------+------+--------+--------+----------------+
```

Someone please explain what is going wrong with the code?

Comment: Percentage means related to 100,you haven't multiplied the last column by 100

Comment: use `(useful/ (useful+funny)) * 100 As useful_percent`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Select should result in an error, because `(Select (useful+funny) from user)` returns more than one row.

You probably want

```
Select
  name,
  fans,
  useful,
  funny,
  100.0 * useful/(useful+funny) As useful_percent
From user
Order by fans desc
limit 10
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend that you use `nullif()` to avoid divide-by-zero problems:

```
Select name, fans, useful, funny,
       useful / nullif(useful + funny, 0) As useful_percent
From user
Order by fans desc
limit 10;
```

As explained in other answers, the subquery is not appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

try this simple query.

```
Select
  name,
  fans,
  useful,
  funny,
  (useful/(useful+funny)) As useful_percent
From user
Order by fans desc
limit 10
```

Or  useful_percent(%) Value then use query like

```
Select
  name,
  fans,
  useful,
  funny,
 ((useful/(useful+funny)) * 100.0)  As useful_percent
From user
Order by fans desc
limit 10
```

Comment: The second one gave the answere. Thanks.